# Any chance of Object auto casting to Integer?

Tags: java

I am wondering whether the below code should work in any scenario?

```
Object value = attValue.getValue(); // Returns an Object, might contain an Integer
        if (value instanceof Integer) { 
            if (mAccount.getValue() != value) { // mAccount.getValue() return int
               // Do something here
            }
        }
```

It works in my Android studio but not in some other's PC. What is making it work for me?

Comment: So if you know `value` is an `instanceOf Integer`   why not just cast it then?

Comment: What happens when it "does not work" on other's PC? Any error message?

Comment: @3kings thats because  OP has mentioned might contain an `integer`. So in case it is not then it will throw `classcastexception`. And thats just because its an Integer object, not primitive. And you are comparing objects , not their values

Comment: gotcha my bad didn't read it well enough.

Comment: @HectorJ, For another person, it is failing compilation with this error - incomparable types: int and Object

Comment: It turns out that for the failing cases, the Android studio was using Java 1.8 for compiling the code. I was using Java 1.7 and I didn't face that issue. Does it really make a difference there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's entirely feasible given the way autoboxing is guaranteed to work on small values, and is permitted to work on larger values. For example, this is guaranteed to print true:

```
Object x = 5;
Object y = 5;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

This *might* print true, but isn't guaranteed to:

```
Object x = 10000;
Object y = 10000;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

I would definitely try not to rely on this in code though, partly because while values in the range of -128 to 127 inclusive are guaranteed to be reused (see [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)), the fact that some JVMs *may* reuse a wider range of values could lead you into a false sense of security about your code.

In your case, we don't know whether you're seeing a difference in platforms (also bearing in mind that we're talking about Android rather than a JVM) or just that when it "worked" the value being boxed was small, and when it "didn't work" it wasn't.

Answer (score 10):

You're getting the same `Integer` instance, since Java 5 there has been an [Integer Cache](http://javapapers.com/java/java-integer-cache/). Because of that cache, you get the same `Integer` reference (you're getting the same `Integer` reference, and because it's the same reference they have **reference** identity - which is what `==` tests). The linked Integer cache document says (in part)

> #### Integer objects are cached internally and reused via the same referenced objects.
>
> This is applicable for Integer values in range between –127 to +127 (Max Integer value).
>
> This Integer caching works only on autoboxing. Integer objects will not be cached when they are built using the constructor.